# Should/could politics and/or political science abide to the same epistemological notions as hard formal-empirical sciences?

Tags: epistemology

Is it reasonable to expect that politics and/or political science should/could abide to the same epistemological notions as hard formal-empirical sciences?

Comment: What do you have in mind by 'epistemological notions ?

Comment: @GeoffreyThomans E.g. repeatability, abiding to logic such as "valid" induction and numerical (e.g. order-related) rules, understanding differences between numerical truth and empirical truth.

Comment: No. The question is rather awkward: politics is a far cry from political science which is a science just by name and 'formal' most often as not is in contrast to 'empirical'. The negative answer boils down to: politics is about taking decisions 'here and now' while science is knowledge sub specie aeternitatis.

Comment: @sand But what I'm asking is that "should/could". I've recognized that political science is science just by name. But I'm asking, whether it should not be, but whether it could become scientific.

Comment: Repeatability? How many times can you rerun the Russian Revolution and change a few variables or tweak a few parameters to see whether things will come out differently, and thereby come up with a theory of Russian Revolutions?

Comment: Science as word, before it was monopolised by scientists merely meant an organised and coherent body of knowledge; that's why I was taken aback to hear of such things as the Islamic Sciences; it's only later that I realised that were still using the original sense of the word and not that they were comparing themselves to biology, biochemistry and the like.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no.

The study of anything which involves psychological metric is limited epistemically as there is no means by which to empirically verify statements of self-knowledge except by the self. And this is the case for every area of study from astrology to economics.

Comment: But there are more aspects to politics than subjective. Since if all was subjective, then e.g. murder could/would be allowed, because it's in accord to the murderer's idea. Therefore for practical reasons, there's at least some objective "domain".

Comment: +1. It's time to start assessing answers on which work has clearly been put in.